# How to save to a database in a Vapor Websocket

Tags: swift, database, postgresql, websocket, vapor

Can't save to postgreSQL Database while in a Vapor Websocket request

I have tried converting to json, parsing json, and implementing normal routing save methods.

```
//TODO:- Connection Websockets to Models
    socketServer.get("api/channel") { ws, req in
        print("Channel Connected \(req)")

//Attempted with On Text Method
        ws.onText { ws, text in
            ws.send("This is pure text \(text)")
            print(text)

        }

//Attempted with On Binary Method
    ws.onBinary { (ws, data) in
        ws.send("data \(data)")
        print(data)

        do {
            let received = try JSONDecoder().decode(ChannelCreateData.self, from: data)

            let account = try ws.requireAuthenticated(CreateAccount.self)

            let channel = try Channel(imageString: received.imageString ?? "", channel: received.channel, createAccountID: account.requireID())
            return channel.save(on: ws)


        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that when data is received from the user using the websocket that data will be saved to my .psql database.